# How can I validate my time integration scheme for my dynamic linear elasticity FEM code with a manufactured solution or similar?

Tags: finite-element, time-integration, verification

I am solving for a dynamic linear elasticity problem:
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 t} - \nabla \cdot \sigma = f   
\end{equation}
where $ u \in R^2 $ with sufficient BCs and initial values both on $ u $ and it's time derevative.

After dicritization with FEM I get the standard:
\begin{equation}
M \ddot{u} + k u = f
\end{equation}
and I can then proceed to use a time some time integration scheme. I opted for a standard explicit Euler. How can I validate my solver?

1. Using a manufactured solution

I am getting the expected convergence rates for a steady state problem but it's not so straightforward for a dynamic simulation because both space and time dicritization errors are present. Even when I refine my mesh to isolate the time discritization errors, but I am not getting small L2 errors. Is there a manufactured solution for such a case in the literature I can validate my code against?

2. Plotting energies

I thought about creating energy plots but they don't seem to have a specific period. I used the boundary conditions defined by the initial solution and the right hand side:

\begin{equation}
u = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(2\pi x) \cos(2\pi y) \cos(20\pi t) ;\\
\sin(2\pi y) \cos(2\pi x) \cos(20\pi t)
\end{bmatrix} 
\quad
f = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1200\pi^2\sin(2\pi x)\cos(20\pi t)\cos(2\pi y) ; \\
1200\pi^2\sin(2\pi y)\cos(20\pi t)\cos(2\pi x)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

on a square domain where I have chosen my lame parameters to be $ \lambda= 0 $ and $ \mu =100 $

[image]

Comment: You should have a second derivative in the first equation. It doesn't let me edit it because the edits are too small.

Comment: You can use a manufactured solution where your spatial field is homogeneous, i.e., the whole field osciallates. That way your spatial discretization error will not bleed into your measurement.

Comment: 1) For the dynamic problem, use a fixed number of mesh elements and compute the error norms with different time steps at a specific time-instant, say t = 0.3. The trend in the resulting error norms should provide information about temporal discretization error.

Comment: Your statement in 2) is unclear. what are you trying to explain here?

Comment: @SthavishthaBhopalam This is a dynamic linear elasticity problem so the plots for energy can give me some insight. I guess. If I start have an initial condition pertaining to a fundamental frequency I'd expect the solution to oscillate at that same frequency.  Right? 
Also, thanks everyone for the comments.